# Add a badge for edits that change tags

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

I don't believe there is a badge for changing tags when editing a post. I would like to propose such a badge. Fixing the tags assigned to a question makes it more visible to experts in those areas, thus resulting in higher quality answers, more activity and happier users. It would be nice to see this behavior get rewarded.

There are badges for editing posts ([Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/3/editor), [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white), [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor)) but they require edits to the title or body -- tag edits don't count towards them. However there are many times when a question is tagged wrong, usually by new users, and other users have to step in and fix it. For example I've [personally fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65775/keith?tab=activity&sort=revisions) 100+ questions that were tagged as [asp-classic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp-classic) but should have been [asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net)/[asp.net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) or vice-versa. (Not that I'm looking to be rewarded, but I'm sure there are others who have fixed a lot more questions than I have and made a significant contribution to cleaning up the site.)

Comment: I just hope you also improved the overall question as good as possible while retagging the question... and flag\vote to close for off-topic questions.

Answer (score 5):

You really should be **improving the entire question**, not just updating a tag. Occasionally, there will be a question that is just... "perfect," for lack of a better term. In those cases, your tag update wouldn't count towards those badges, you are correct.

Additionally, with enough reputation, tags can be easily edited [inline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), without ever having to actually "edit" the question. I can easily see why they consciously choose to not make it count towards those badges, as this could potentially be abused.

That being said, I could possibly argue that a good solution would be to include tag changes in the criteria for the badges that require you to edit a post at a *lower conversion rate*. Say, for every five posts you change **only** the tags in, that counts for **one** "edited post" for the sake of the badges. Though I doubt this would get serious consideration.

---

My ultimate advice: just improve the entire question. Fix spelling, formatting, grammar, *and* update the tags. If you really can't improve the question in any way, then take one for the team and know you're still helping improve the community.

Comment: I would argue that fixing the tags is a more valuable action than fixing spelling and grammar, because fixing the tags makes the question more visible to the right audience.

Comment: @Keith It may be a more valuable _single_ change, but really it's moot without fixing everything.

Comment: The changes that a question really needs no other help other than just a tag change is pretty low, IMO.